# In Tkinter how do i remove focus from a widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'd like to remove focus from a widget manually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can focus to another dummy widget.

**Edit**

```
from Tkinter import *

def callback():
    print master.focus()

master = Tk()
e = Entry(master)
e.pack()
e.focus()
b = Button(master, text="get", width=10, command=callback)
b.pack()

master.mainloop()
```

Focusing on a non-'focusable' widget will remove focus from another widget.

Comment: Not a dummy widget, it has to be a real widget.

Comment: all widgets can receive focus. What do you mean by "non-focusable"?

Comment: @Bryan: All widgets can receive focus. For example, when you focus on an Entry widget, you see the cursor; when you focus on a Button, it has another effect. On the other hand, when you focus on the TK(), as far as I can tell, it doesn't have any effect like the others. I am not sure how to exactly remove focus from a widget, but this might be a way around to do it.

Comment: If your program has focus (is the active window), some part of your program has to have focus. I just set focus on a convenient frame widget. It doesn't appear to do anything currently. Yeah, still using tkinter in 2018

Answer (score 5):

- Set focus to another widget to remove focus from the target widget is a good idea. There are two methods for this: `w.focus_set()` and `w.focus_force()`. However, method `w.focus_force()` is impolite. It's better to wait for the window manager to give you the focus. Setting focus to parent widget or to the root window removes focus from the target widget.
- Some widgets have `takefocus` option. Set takefocus to 0 to take your widget out of focus traversal (when user hits `<Tab>` key).

Answer (score 4):

My solution is `root.focus()` it will remove widget focus.

Answer (score 2):

If the dummy widget is `Canvas` then `c.focus()` will not work.

use `c.focus_set()` or `c.tk.call('focus',c)` to first focus on the canvas window itself.

---

That's because

`c.focus()`

> ... returns the id for the item that currently has the focus, or an empty string if no item has the focus. [Reference](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M50)

`c.focus(id_)` will focus on the item having id `id_` within the canvas.

`c.focus("")` will remove the focus from any item in the canvas.

---

Hence (within some callback)

```py
c.config(highlightthickness = 0) # to remove the highlight border on focus
c.foucs_set()
c.focus("") # just to be sure
```

---

The reason `c.focus()` functions differently is that within Tcl/Tk's [Commands](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/contents.htm) there's the "Primary" Command [`focus`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/focus.htm)

as well as the Canvas-specific Widget Command [`focus`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M50)

That's not an issue within the Tcl/Tk syntax but in the tkinter module `c.focus()` will call the underlying canvas-specific `foucs`.

From `tkinter.py` within the `Canvas` class Line 2549

```py
def focus(self, *args):
        """Set focus to the first item specified in ARGS."""
        return self.tk.call((self._w, 'focus') + args)
```

Comment: Tested on python 3.7.14 and TkVersion 8.6

Answer (score 1):

If you use ttk widgets you can "remove" the focus ring by removing the color; for example on a button:

```
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure('TButton', focuscolor='')
```

Answer (score 1):

So the question may be a duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55583093/how-to-remove-focus-out-of-a-text-widget-in-tkinter-python?rq=1), but the answer from @Bryan Oakley works perfectly for me in Python 3.8

```
root.focus_set()
```

Too easy...