# How to remove focus out of a Text widget in Tkinter, Python

Tags: python, tkinter

By placing a Text widget in my GUI

```
from Tkinter import Text
textBox=Text(root, height=20, width=10)
textBox.pack()
```

whenever I write something in that box, I cant return the focus back to any other place in the window. I have some keys bounded to event, which stop working after I wrote in the Text widget.

Is there a way of redirecting the focus to another place after writing text?

Comment: bind keys to main window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way of redirecting the focus to another place after writing text?

Every widget has a method named `focus_set` which can be used to move keyboard focus to that widget.

For example, to set the focus to the root window you would do:

```
root.focus_set()
```

Comment: What if the canvas and widgets are packed within the root? This does not change the focus, which was already practically on the root?

Comment: @hirschme: I don't understand your question. `focus_set` absolutely will change the focus if you call it on a widget that doesn't have focus (and which is able to accept focus). If you call it on a widget that already has focus, then nothing will change.  Keyboard focus can only ever be on one widget at a time. The fact that widgets are or aren't packed in a common parent doesn't affect the focus at all.

Answer (score 2):

Please press Return-Key to give focus back to window

```
import tkinter as tk


def onReturn(*event):

    root.focus_set()
    
    
root = tk.Tk()

textBox= tk.Text(root, height=20, width=10)
textBox.pack()

root.bind("<Return>", onReturn)

root.mainloop()
```