# How do I remove focus and cursor on my entry widget in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to make a search bar for my UI for a uniform shop as part of my assignment, the codes are as followed:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time
import sqlite3
from tkinter import simpledialog
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkcalendar import *
from tkinter import ttk
import math
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import winsound

##-------------Frames setup--------------------------
class VendingApp(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(Store)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        #Destroys current frame and replaces it with a new one.
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()

class Store(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        def testfunc():
            None

        def callback_entry1_focus(event):
            search_ent.config(state = NORMAL)
            search_ent.delete(0, END)


        def callback_entry2_focus(event):
            search_ent.config(state = DISABLED)



        self._images = list()

        img_banner = Image.open("pic/banner.jpg")
        img_banner = img_banner.resize((400, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        banner = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_banner)
        self._images.append(banner)

        ##---------------------pictures and filters Store------------------------------------
        PicFrame = Frame(self, width=400, height=100)
        PicFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        PicFrame.grid_propagate(False)


        canvas_for_banner = Canvas(PicFrame, height=100, width=400 ) # banner image
        canvas_for_banner.pack(anchor = N)
        canvas_for_banner['highlightthickness'] = 0
        canvas_for_banner.grid_propagate(False)
        canvas_for_banner.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=banner)
 ##---------------------------------Midd store-------------------
        FilterFrame =Frame(self, width=400, height=930, relief = RAISED, bd =1)
        FilterFrame.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        FilterFrame.pack_propagate(0)


        search_ent = Entry(FilterFrame, font = ('Helvetica', 20))
        search_ent.pack(ipady = 15, ipadx = 136, pady = (0,80))
        search_ent.insert(0, "Search for item here....")
        search_ent.bind("<FocusIn>", callback_entry1_focus)
        search_ent.bind("<FocusOut>", callback_entry2_focus)

        Ava_title = Label(FilterFrame, text = "Availability", font = ('Helvetica', 20, 'bold'))
        Ava_title.pack()
        self.stock_yes = IntVar()
        self.stock_no = IntVar()

        check_ava = Checkbutton(FilterFrame, text = 'Avaliable', variable = self.stock_yes, font = 20, command = testfunc)
        check_ava.pack( anchor = 'w', padx = 30, pady =10)

        check_unava = Checkbutton(FilterFrame, text = 'Unavaliable', font = 20, variable = self.stock_no, command = testfunc)
        check_unava.pack(anchor = 'w', padx = 30, pady = 10)



        gend_title = Label(FilterFrame, text = "Gender", font = ('Helvetica', 20, 'bold'))
        gend_title.pack(pady = (30,0))
        self.boi = IntVar()
        self.girl = IntVar()

        check_boi = Checkbutton(FilterFrame, text = 'Male', font = 20, variable = self.boi)
        check_boi.pack( anchor = 'w', padx = 30, pady = 10)

        cehck_girl = Checkbutton(FilterFrame, text = 'Female', font = 20, variable = self.girl)
        cehck_girl.pack(anchor = 'w', padx = 30, pady =10)



        Class_title = Label(FilterFrame, text = "Uniform class", font = ('Helvetica', 20, 'bold'))
        Class_title.pack(pady = (30,0))
        self.formal = IntVar()
        self.sport = IntVar()

        check_formal = Checkbutton(FilterFrame, text = 'Formal', font = 20, variable = self.formal)
        check_formal.pack( anchor = 'w', padx = 30, pady =10)

        check_sport = Checkbutton(FilterFrame, text = 'Sport', font = 20, variable = self.sport)
        check_sport.pack(anchor = 'w', padx = 30, pady =10)



        type_title = Label(FilterFrame, text = "Type", font = ('Helvetica', 20, 'bold'))
        type_title.pack(pady = (30,0))
        self.shirts = IntVar()
        self.pants = IntVar()
        self.misc  = IntVar()

        check_shirts = Checkbutton(FilterFrame, text = 'Shirts', font = 20, variable = self.shirts)
        check_shirts.pack( anchor = 'w', padx = 30, pady =10)

        check_pants = Checkbutton(FilterFrame, text = 'Pants', font = 20, variable = self.pants)
        check_pants.pack(anchor = 'w', padx = 30, pady =10)

        check_misc = Checkbutton(FilterFrame, text = 'Misc', font = 20, variable = self.misc)
        check_misc.pack(anchor = 'w', padx = 30, pady =10)







        MidFrame = Frame(self,width = 1520, height = 1030, relief = SUNKEN, bd = 2)
        MidFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 1, rowspan = 2)
        MidFrame.grid_propagate(False)


        BottomFrame = Frame(self,width = 1920, height = 50, bd = 2, relief = RAISED)
        BottomFrame.grid(row = 2, column =0, columnspan = 2)
        BottomFrame.pack_propagate(False)



#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = VendingApp()
    #Renames the TITLE of the window
    root.title("Vending machine")
    root.geometry("1920x1080")
    root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    root.resizable(False, False)
    root.mainloop()
```

The code works as intended. When I click onto the entry field, the text deletes. I am trying to make it so that when users don't use it anymore, the text returns, but no matter where I click on the screen, the entry widget won't unfocus. Is there any way to "unfocus"? Or am I just doing it the wrong way? All answers are apreciated.

Comment: please provide a [mre] for us.

Comment: Is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4299744/11106801 what you are looking for?